# ILoop w/ SBT 0.11

Tags: scala, sbt

Was wondering if someone could help me figure out, why launching a REPL utilizing ILoop's 'break' method results in me getting a REPL that hangs when I issue the first command?

I have the correct classpath loaded up utilizing 'MyType'.

-- Using SBT 0.11 and Scala 2.9.1

Thanks!

Comment: What does the code launching the REPL looks like? And do you use stdin for anything in your program? Do you have multiple threads? What sort of command have you tried? Have you reproduced this with a very small program?

Comment: The question was also posted to the mailing list with sample code where it was answered: https://groups.google.com/group/simple-build-tool/browse_thread/thread/f1799b6de359c4.  Please cross-link when posting in multiple locations so that people don't waste time on an already answered question.